# maven pom.xml complains that a execution cannot resolve dependencies but functions correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, wsdl2java

I have a Java project that uses a WSDL service.  The pom gives an error (so there is the red X on my project) but everything builds and runs correctly.  I am quite stumped, any ideas are appricated.

Here is the trouble maker:

```xml
< !-- WSDL stub generation -- >
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId >cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf-codegen-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/wsdl/Service.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is the error I get from the execution element above:

> Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.2:wsdl2java failed: Plugin org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:jar:2.7.2 () (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.2:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)

(Sorry for the spaces around the '<' and '>'.  I am new to S.O. and cannot yet post pictures.

Comment: That plugins generate the Java classes asociated to your WSDL. Maybe you already have them (manually) created, so that the plugin fails but not the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it probably means that the Maven cannot find the dependency but it still exist on your class path nonetheless.... It might be provided by the servlet container.